# how to add a value to the end of a pandas column without index

Tags: python, pandas, object, indexing, append

i have a Dataframe which i want to add values to end of a column inside it, *without using index* as i'm doing this inside an object,
pandas append didnt work for me for some reason, i tried to add it straight forward and also in another dataframe  (x in the code).
i wanted something like:

```
DB=pd.DataFrame(columns=['reviews'])
DB= DB.append(object)# append to reviews column, reviews is also an object
```

but when i do it i get and error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'DB' referenced before assignment
```

im expecteing to get something like:

```
    reviews
0  <__main__.Review object at 0x0000020D2A14BD48>
1  <__main__.Review object at 0x0000020D29F17D88>
```

my code goes like this:

```
DB=pd.DataFrame(columns=['reviews'])

class Review:

    def __init__(self, json_string):
       self.json_string=json_string

    def get_text(self):
       json_dict=json.loads(self.json_string)
       return json_dict['body']



class ReviewSearchEngine:

    def __init__(self):
       pass

    def add(self, review:Review):
      
        x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['reviews'])
        x.loc[0, 'reviews'] = review
        ****DB= DB.append(x)****
        return
if __name__ == '__main__':

    search_engine = ReviewSearchEngine()
    file_path = "./review_data.txt"  
    lines = open(file_path).readlines()
    for line in lines:
       review = Review(line) # review is an object
       search_engine.add(review)
```

Comment: `DB` is defined outside of the class. You should define it in the class in `__init__`

Comment: Could you please provide a sample output? Is it a string you are trying to append with Reviews column? For eg., appending a name to 'Reviews'?

Comment: thanks, it is working(when i added it to the attributes actually) but now i get index 0 for for all the reviews from x, and when im trying DB.append(reviews) i get an error. so im stuck with the same problem, isnt there any method that works as a list?

Comment: added in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested you try this:

```
class Review:

    def __init__(self, json_string):
        self.json_string = json_string

    def get_text(self):
        json_dict = json.loads(self.json_string)
        return json_dict['body']


class ReviewSearchEngine:

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def add(self, review: Review):
        x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['reviews'])
        x.loc[0, 'reviews'] = review
        self.db = self.db.append(x, ignore_index=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DB = pd.DataFrame(columns=['reviews'])

    search_engine = ReviewSearchEngine(DB)
    file_ = "stack.txt"
    lines = open(file_).readlines()
    for line in lines:
        review = Review(line)  # review is an object
        search_engine.add(review)
    print(search_engine.__dict__['db'])

>>>                                       reviews
0  <__main__.Review object at 0x000001B497563400>
1  <__main__.Review object at 0x000001B4975634F0>
2  <__main__.Review object at 0x000001B49754DEE0>
```

Please specify argument `ignore_index=True` when method `pd.DataFrame.append` to avoid unexpected indexes.